# Как обрабатывать ошибки MVC PHP?

Tags: php, mvc, обработка-ошибок

Всем привет. Пишу свою библиотеку для разработки приложений. Сейчас встал серьезный вопрос о том, как обрабатывать ошибки и исключения. Было решено использовать методы регистрации ошибок, фатальных ошибок и исключений. Заметил странность, что `set_error_handler` и `register_shutdown_function` при ***headers already sent by*** срабатывает дважды. Проблема сейчас заключается в том, что я не могу сделать редирект на страницу ошибки: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`. Ошибку вызвал специально в **view**, чтобы проверить, то есть после рендеринга страницы.

А вообще задача стоит в том, чтобы отобразить либо страницу ошибки с подробностями, либо страницу ошибки без них.

Каким образом я могу решить проблему с дублированием ошибок и сделать редирект при необходимости?

```
<?php

namespace Core;

use Helpers\Config;
use Helpers\File;
use Helpers\Url;

/**
 * Class ErrorHandler
 * Обработчик ошибок и исключений
 * @package Сore
 */
class ErrorHandler
{
    /**
     * @var array Константа ассоциаций кода ошибок к тексту
     */
    const ERRORS = [
        E_ERROR => 'ERROR',
        E_WARNING => 'WARNING',
        E_PARSE => 'PARSE',
        E_NOTICE => 'NOTICE',
        E_CORE_ERROR => 'CORE_ERROR',
        E_CORE_WARNING => 'CORE_WARNING',
        E_COMPILE_ERROR => 'COMPILE_ERROR',
        E_COMPILE_WARNING => 'COMPILE_WARNING',
        E_USER_ERROR => 'USER_ERROR',
        E_USER_WARNING => 'USER_WARNING',
        E_USER_NOTICE => 'USER_NOTICE',
        E_STRICT => 'STRICT',
        E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR => 'RECOVERABLE_ERROR',
        E_DEPRECATED => 'DEPRECATED',
        E_USER_DEPRECATED => 'USER_DEPRECATED',
    ];

    public static $status;

    /**
     * Регистрация методов управления ошибками и исключениями.
     * Включение отображения ошибок
     */
    public static function register()
    {
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        # Управление ошибками
        set_error_handler([__CLASS__, 'errorHandler']);
        # Управление фатальными ошибками
        register_shutdown_function([__CLASS__, 'fatalErrorHandler']);
        # Управление исключениями
        set_exception_handler([__CLASS__, 'exceptionHandler']);
    }

    /**
     * Управление ошибками
     * @param $errno Код (номер) ошибки
     * @param $errstr Сообщение ошибки
     * @param $errfile Файл ошибки
     * @param $errline Строка в файле ошикбки
     * @return bool Предотвращение дальнейшего выполнения
     */
    public static function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
        self::show($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline);
        # Не передается ошибка далее на обработку
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Отображение ошибок на экран
     * @param $errno Код (номер) ошибки
     * @param $errstr Сообщение ошибки
     * @param $errfile Файл ошибки
     * @param $errline Строка в файле ошикбки
     */
    private static function show($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
        http_response_code(self::$status);
        echo "[" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "] <b>" . self::getErrorName($errno) .
            "</b> в файле {$errfile} на строке <b>{$errline}</b>:<br>{$errstr}<br>";
        $message = "[" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "]" . self::getErrorName($errno) .
            " в файле {$errfile} на строке {$errline}:" . PHP_EOL . $errstr . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        self::writeLog($message);
    }

    /**
     * Получение наименования класса ошибки по ее коду
     * @param $error integer Номер ошибки
     * @return string Наименование класса ошибки
     */
    private static function getErrorName($error)
    {
        $error_name = $error;
        if (array_key_exists($error, self::ERRORS)) {
            $error_name = self::ERRORS[$error];
        }

        return $error_name;
    }


    private static function writeLog($message)
    {
        $errors_config_section = Config::getSettings('logs', 'errors');
        $log_file = File::createFile($errors_config_section['filename'], $errors_config_section['extension'], LOG);
        File::write($log_file, $message);

        header("Location: " . Url::to($errors_config_section['controller'], self::$status));
    }

    /**
     * Управление фатальными ошибками
     * @return bool Предотвращение дальнейшего выполнения
     */
    public static function fatalErrorHandler(int $status = 500)
    {
        self::$status = $status;
        if (!empty($error = error_get_last()) && $error['type'] && (E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR)) {
            ob_get_clean();
            self::show($error['type'], $error['message'], $error['file'], $error['line']);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Управление исключениями
     * @param \Exception|\Error $ex Исключение
     * @return bool Предотвращение дальнейшего выполнения
     */
    public static function exceptionHandler($ex, int $status = 500)
    {
        self::$status = $status;
        self::show(get_class($ex), $ex->getMessage(), $ex->getFile(), $ex->getLine());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно, при чем тут редирект.

Редирект - это самое неправильное, что только можно сделать при ошибке.

Существует такая вещь, как коды возврата НТТР. Вещь чрезвычайно полезная и удобная.
Она сообщает клиенту, чем завершился его запрос.
Соответственно, обманывать клиента не следует. А следует отдавать ровно тот код возврата, который соответствует статусу страницы.
Если после завершения обработки запроса следует запросить другой урл - тогда отправляем код 3хх и заголовок Location:. Но если выполнение запроса завершилось с ошибкой, то единственно правильным кодом ответа будет 500, без каких-бы то ни было редиректов.

Код отображения страницы оибки отличается только проверкой переменной, которая отвечает за режим сайта - боевой или в разработке. И в зависимости от этот выводятся подобности, или нет. Код же возврата остается одним и тем же - 500, без редиректов.

Отлов ошибок при рендеринге - это один из немногих случаев, когда включение буфеиринга оправдано. Но не следует увлекаться буфферингом - как и любое сообщение об ошибке, Cannot modify header information служит для помощи программисту. И без нужды затыкать эту ошибку не следует. То есть, буфферинг включать только перед тем, как начинается непосредственно вывод во View

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. По поводу кодов возврата HTTP: если есть `error`, скажем *No such file or directory*, то код возврата будет 200. Иные он приобретает в случае `fatal error` или  `exception`. В данный момент я делаю механизм. Полностью солидарен с ошибкой 500 и страницами. В данный момент кроется проблема и непонимание именно работы с ошибками и перенаправление на стилизованную страницу ошибки. Как я понял, то редирект на страницу с кодом можно сделать, но надо включить буферизацию перед рендерингом, и это есть адекватное решение, так?

Comment: **если выполнение запроса завершилось с ошибкой, то единственно правильным кодом ответа будет 500, без каких-бы то ни было редиректов**

Comment: а если надо показать красивую страницу? То придется делать редирект, так как url может быть кастомный (ЧПУ или нет)

Comment: Я не в состоянии понять эту проблему. Почему обработчик ошибок не может показать красивую страницу сам? при чем здесь урл? Послушайте. Перед тем, как "писать свою библиотеку для разработки приложений", сделайте себе одолжение, ознакомьтесь с тем, как работают существующие библиотеки. Хотя бы самые базовые принципы.

Comment: адекватно ли следующее: я вызываю exception только в случае краха приложения или методов (соединения с БД), которые критичны. ошибки в режиме разработчика я вывожу на экран специальной страницы, а в случае режима релиза, то все ошибки не отображаются и обрабатываются как функция, вернувшая false с массивом текстов ошибок, если надо.

Comment: Честно говоря, я ничего не понял. по мне, обработчик ошибок делается совершенно тупо - условие проверяет настройки окружения и если это дев сервер, то отображаются подробности, иначе все подробности идут в лог, ваыдается код 500 и читается html страницу для пользователя. А кто там кидает исключение - сам программист или РНР - это без разницы.

Comment: полностью согласен с вами. В принципе, подытожив, можно сказать, что все в голове уложилось. А вот на методы `unlink`, `mkdir` и другие, которые возвращаются false в случае ошибки вы кидаете `exception` или нет?

Comment: mkdir порождает ошибку в случае ошибки, то есть ничего специально кидать не надо

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно буферизовать рендеринг view с помощью ob_start() и выводить его в поток  только если все ок. В этом случае никакого "headers already sent by" не произойдет.

Comment: Сергей, спасибо за ответ. Правильно ли я понимаю, что если там будет ошибки (внутри view), то с применением буферизации она также поймается?

Comment: конечно, поймается